# Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type

Tags: vb.net, keydown

In my Form_Load

```
AddHandler KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown
RaiseEvent KeyDown(Me, e)

Event KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Control Then
        MsgBox("test")
    End If
End Sub
```

I get this error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type

What should i do to catch keydown event?

---

Here is my code :

I have the form load function :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AddHandler KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown
    RaiseEvent KeyDown(Me, e)
```

End Sub

I have the event declaration :

```
    Event KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
```

And the function which should open MsgBox When control key is pressed :

```
    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Control Then
        MsgBox("test")
    End If
End Sub
```

But I have this error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type

So i do not know what should i do

Comment: AddHandler KeyDown, AddressOf Form1_KeyDown 

RaiseEvent KeyDown(Me, e)

Comment: I tried formatting your code, but it was not clear to me if it was intended to be all one block - please adjust as necessary. Also, the last part of the error message is missing.